# 'Desactivar' un elemento en HTML

Tags: jquery, css, html5, bootstrap, css3

Necesito 'desactivar' un elemento `<a>`, después de haber dado clic sobre el. Estoy utilizando Bootstrap, al momento de dar clic sobre un elemento `<a>`, se abre un modal y al cerrarlo, el elemento `<a>` sigue como si estuviera 'seleccionado'. ¿Cómo lo puedo quitar?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Esto es un ejemplo</a>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Example</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Example</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: podrías sustituir la etiqueta `a` por una etiqueta `label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por temas de accesibilidad, después de que se cierra un modal, el `focus` debe regresar al elemento que lo lanzó. Por lo tanto no puedes quitarle el `focus` a tu link después de utilizarlo.  Referencias: [Respuesta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35859494), [Issue en GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/12364)

Sin embargo, si no deseas que visualmente se muestre como seleccionado, puedes agregar reglas de css para `a:focus` y `a:hover`:

```
    a:focus {
      color: #337ab7 !important;
      outline: none !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
    }

    a:hover {
      color: #23527c !important;
      text-decoration: underline !important;
    }
```

Tu código completo quedaría así:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      a:focus {
        color: #337ab7 !important;
        outline: none !important;
        text-decoration: none !important;
      }
      a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline !important;
        color: #23527c !important;
      }
    </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Esto es un ejemplo</a>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Example</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Example</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para quitar realmente el foco de `a` deberías utilizar [blur()](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) sobre `a` cuando cierres el modal, así de primeras te debería quedar algo como lo siguiente:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('a').blur();
});
```